# Windows network places problem

Tags: networking, internet, lan

**Here is my setup:**

1. I have an ADSL router with internet connection, IP address: 192.168.1.1
2. I have a 100 Mbps Dax network switch with 8 ports.
3. I have two computers with the IP addresses 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.4

**What I have done?**

- I connected my 2 computers and the ADSL router to the 8 port network switch.
- Both computers are in same work group. Both has the default gateway as 192.168.1.1. Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Run the 'Setup a home or small office network' wizard with the second option - "connects through the residential gateway".

**What I can do?**

- Both computers can connect to internet through the router.
- Both computers can ping either the other computer and the router.

**What is my problem?**

- I cannot access the shared files and folders on the other computer from one computer.
- I cannot access the other system with Remote Desktop connection.
- I cannot access the computer if i run \computer1
- I can access the local apache server running on one system from other system by putting the IP address in the browser.

Can somebody help me with my "Cannot's"?

Comment: the firewalls are off and remote desktop is turned on. and i don't need remote desktop. i was just checking that.

Comment: Do you have a third party firewall, like Symantec/Norton/McAfee installed?

Comment: You do not need to run any network setup thing. Just make sure firewall rules and sharing rules are good. For test, disable the firewall and try like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your firewall is probably blocking the services, and remote desktop may be turned off. See my suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/98061/how-do-you-share-files-between-windows-7-and-windows-xp/98063#98063).

Comment: Also disable Simple File Sharing (This option is present in Folder options)